# Ignoring/skipping tokens using std::cin

Tags: c++, scanf, cin, skip

With `scanf` one is allowed to *skip* matched tokens, simply adding `*` to the pattern, as in:

```
int first, second;
scanf("%d %*s %d", &first, &second);
```

Is there any equivalent approach with `std::cin`? Something like (of course, sparing the usage of additional variables):

```
int first, second;
std::cin >> first >> `std::skip` >> second;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a simple task for input streams in C++ to do same thing. Function `scanf` gets all expected format: `"%d %*s %d"` and can look ahead to determine what's going on.

On the other hand, operator `>>` just tries to satisfy current entry parameter.

---

You have chances to write you own istream manipulator to eat inputs until reaching a digit.

Try this my naive code:

```
template<typename C, typename T>
basic_istream<C, T>&
eat_until_digit(basic_istream<C, T>& in)
{
  const ctype<C>& ct = use_facet <ctype<C>> (in.getloc());

  basic_streambuf<C, T>* sb = in.rdbuf();

  int c = sb->sgetc();
  while (c != T::eof() && !ct.is(ctype_base::digit, c))
      c = sb->snextc();

  if (c == T::eof())
      in.setstate(ios_base::eofbit);

  return in;
}

int main()
{
    int first, second;

    cin >> first >> eat_until_digit >> second;

    cout << first << " : " << second << endl;
}
```

You can extend and improve above code to achieve what you need.

Comment: +1 Sounds reasonable! ^^ And what about a set of skips, like `std::ios::skip::str`, `std::ios::skip::dec`, and even `std::ios::skip::any`? Too messy? (:

Comment: Doesn't `std::ctype::scan_is` do this?

Comment: @0x499602D2: `scan_is` is useful to find masks and somehow can be used **inside** the above function since the OP needs an IO manipulator to consume the input like `cin >> eat_until_digit`

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking for [C++ String Toolkit Library](http://www.partow.net/programming/strtk/index.html).

Check this for more [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23198/C-String-Toolkit-StrTk-Tokenizer)

Or you may try with `ignore` function like this:

```
std::cin >> val1;
std::cin.ignore (1234, ' ');
std::cin >> val3;
```

Something like this:-

```
template <class charT, class traits>
inline std::basic_istream<charT, traits> &
ignoreToken (std::basic_istream<charT, traits> &strm)
{
    strm.ignore (1234, ' ');
    return strm;
}
```

And then use like:

```
cin >> val1 >> ignoreToken >> val3 >> ignoreToken >> val5;
```

Comment: Although it seems to be the only available option from stl, I was expecting something a bit neatier. A `std::ios::skip::str` and `std::ios::skip::dec` and even `std::ios::skip::any` would be very nice (:

Comment: +1 I never meant your post didn't help! ^^ Thanks for the functional example! (:

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use a dummy variable

```
int first, second;
std::string dummy;
cin >> first >> dummy >> second;
```

but there's no direct equivalent AFAIK.

Comment: Yes, that's why I pointed "*of course, sparing the usage of additional vars*". I'm getting used to the idea of this being the only solution, anyway \=

Comment: @Rubens, sorry missed that.